# how to check response value in node js using switch case

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have one method in which I am using switch statement. I want to pass its response back to caller and then do the next operation. I am stuck in that as I am new to node js. Below is my code.

```js
const getCustDetails = (id, source) => {
getDetails(id, source)
              .then((Data) => {
                //do some operation here but its getting error as - TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
              })
              .catch((e) => {
                logger.error({
                  method: "calcAndSaveBoiler_getEntityDetails",
                  message: e.response
                    ? JSON.stringify(e.response.data.response_message)
                    : e,
                });
                parseError(e, res);
              });
}
```

My getDetails method is as follows.

```js
const getDetails = (Id, source) => {
  switch (convertToLowerCase(source) )) {
    case abc:
      getService(Id, source);
      break;
    case pqr:
      getService(Id, source);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```

I am stuck here to know how can I make sure that its response will present in parent method call and then I can use it for some other operation.

Comment: Your `getDetails` is not returning any value. You would need to return the values you get from `getService`

Comment: @MinusFour how can I do it. I am struggling there only. Can you please help. Thanks

Comment: @MinusFour I have just added return statement before service call and it worked. Thanks for the direction,

Answer (score 0):

I have just added a return statement like below in switch case.

```js
const getDetails = (Id, source) => {
  switch (convertToLowerCase(source) )) {
    case abc:
      getService(Id, source);
      break;
    case pqr:
      getService(Id, source);
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};
```